# Implementing authentication with AngularJS and ui-router

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router

I am trying to deal with authentication with ui-router and angularJS, i would like to achieve this normal scenario where:

- if (user is not authenticated && state requires authentication) then
  go to 'login' state
- else if (user is authenticated && state does not require authentication) then
  go to 'main' state
- else go to state requested by the user.

i have implemented it in a way i am not sure is correct and i need some validation here from you guys.

I have a resolve function that retrieving the information whether user is authenticated from the server, if it rejected, then I send the user to 'login' state in $stateChangeError. if it resolved I handle the other logic in $stateChangeSuccess.

But as I understand that the information would only be available in $stateChangeSuccess and not in $stateChangeStart , therefore if I implement the logic i wrote above in $stateChangeSucceess then some of the pages will flicker before the transition ends.

Please advise. Is there another way or a way to improve this solution ?. I thought of making a resolve function for each state , check if the user is authenticated and make the routing there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with single page apps. One of the solutions that I use in my angular pages is to cache the userid and the fact that the user is authenticated in local storage. You can add an expiry to this as well. Here's a link to the local storage module: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage (there are others too).

Then in each state you can check to see if the user has already been authenticated rather than going back to the server each time. Also, this will help the back/fwd buttons work better. Typically in your controller you'd have code to check if the user is authenticated (which would probably go and check local storage for a flag and get the userinfo which was initially retrieved from the server).

I can see some security issues with this though if the browser is being shared by multiple users.

This article seems to list a better/newer way to do this: https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

Answer (score 0):

using `run`function in your module combining with a service that knows if the user it's authenticated:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .run(runFn);
runFn.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'MyAuthService', '$state'];
function runFn($rootScope, MyAuthService, $state){

   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

          var userAuthenticated =   MyAuthService.isLogged();

          //* check if the user it's present on cookies
          //if(!userAuthenticated && $cookieStore.get('user_token'))
          //  If the token is in the cookies i get the user from server
          //else
          // $state.go('login')

          //your logic here
          /*if (user is not authenticated && state requires authentication) then $state.go('login')*/

    });

}
```

This function will be executed always that a state change.

Comment: Thanks. how can I be sure that the service MyAuthService is holding the information of whether the user is logged in or not when I execute the line you mentioned 'var userAuthenticated =   MyAuthService.isLogged();' ? currently I am sending an api call to check this. is there any other way?

Comment: Generally, i use cookies for this. check my edited answer. For more clearity, read this excelent article https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication